# Remover todos os elementos de um array que já existam em outro

Tags: javascript, array, lista

Tenho dois *arrays* com objetos em javascript:

```
var a = [{objeto1}, {objeto2}, {objeto3}, {objeto4}, {objeto5}];
var b = [{objeto1}, {objeto2}];
```

Como faço para o que estiver no array `b` sair do array `a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você pode fazer seguinte.:

```js
var objeto1 = { value: 'A' };
var objeto2 = { value: 'B' };
var objeto3 = { value: 'C' };
var objeto4 = { value: 'D' };
var objeto5 = { value: 'E' };

var listaA = [objeto1, objeto2, objeto3, objeto4, objeto5];
var listaB = [objeto1, objeto2];

listaA = listaA.filter(function (objeto) { 
  return listaB.indexOf(objeto) == -1 
});
console.log(listaA);
```

Mas lembre-se que a comparação de objetos é feito por referencia, então mesmo que ambos os objetos tenham exatamente as mesmas propriedades e valores, eles ainda serão considerados como diferentes.

```js
var objeto1 = { value: 'A' };
var objeto2 = Object.assign({}, objeto1);
console.log(objeto1, objeto2, objeto1 == objeto2);
```

Opcionalmente, você pode comparar os objetos usando o hash do mesmo.

```js
Array.prototype.except = function(lista) {
  lista = lista.map(function (object) {
    return objectHash.sha1(object);
  });
  return this.filter(function (objeto) { 
    var objHash = objectHash.sha1(objeto)
    return lista.indexOf(objHash) == -1;
  });
}

var listaA = [
  { value: 'A' }, 
  { value: 'B' }, 
  { value: 'C' }, 
  { value: 'D' }, 
  { value: 'E' }
];
var listaB = [
  { value: 'B' }, 
  { value: 'D' }
];
var lista = listaA.except(listaB);
console.log(lista);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/puleos/object-hash/master/dist/object_hash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ótima observação com relação a referência dos objetos.

Comment: @MarcioEric editei a resposta, uma alternativa caso precise comparar os objetos pelo o seu valor.

Answer (score 2):

Outra opção é remover o index do próprio array:

```js
var a = [{a: 1}, {b: 1}, {c:1}, {d:1}, {e:1}];
var b = [{b:1}, {e:1}];

a.map(function(item, index){
  JSON.stringify(b).indexOf(JSON.stringify(item)) == -1 ? '' : a.splice(index,1) ;
});

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer remover todos os elementos contidos no `array` `a` do `array` `b`, você pode utilizar a função `filter`:

```
var c = a.filter(function(item) {
  return b.indexOf(item) === -1; // Não foi encontrado
});
```

Os elementos retornados serão os que obtiverem um resultado `true`, ou seja, que não estiverem contidos no `array` `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Só fazer um `filter` e verificar com o `includes` se cada item do array `a` existe no array `b`.

Só lembre-se que comparação de objetos é sempre feita por referência, ou seja, mesmo que as propriedades de dois objetos tenham os mesmos valores eles não são iguais.

```js
var obj1 = { value: 'A' };
var obj2 = { value: 'B' };
var obj3 = { value: 'C' };
var obj4 = { value: 'E' };

var a = [ obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];
var b = [ obj1, obj2 ];

a = a.filter(function(el) {
  return !b.includes(el);
} );

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função nativa do Javascript [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

> O método splice() altera o conteúdo de uma lista, adicionando novos elementos enquanto remove elementos antigos.

A função recebe até três parâmetros, mas nós precisamos apenas dos dois primeiros. O primeiro é o índice no qual você vai remover alguma coisa, e o segundo parâmetro é a quantidade de itens que você quer remover a partir daquele índice.

Logo:

```
var objeto1 = {}, objeto2 = {}, objeto3 = {};
var a = [objeto1, objeto2, objeto3];
var b = [objeto2];

for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
    if (b.indexOf(a[i]) > -1) {
        a = a.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Ao final do código acima, o vetor `a` conterá apenas os objetos `objeto1` e `objeto3`.

Note que a comparação entre objetos no Javascript, utilizada internamente pelo método `indexOf` do vetor, é por referência. Esse tipo de comparação funciona se você adicionar os mesmos objetos aos dois vetores. Se você adicionar objetos distintos, porém com propriedades semelhantes, você ainda vai precisar implementar uma função para buscar os objetos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar essa função

```
  copiarObjeto(original){
    var copia = original instanceof Array ? [] : {};
    for (let i in original) {
      if (original[i] && typeof original[i] == 'object') copia[i] = this.copiarObjeto(original[i]);
      else copia[i] = original[i];
    }
    return copia;
  }
```